# Visual Basic: how to execute commands in cmd without pressing "ENTER" by user?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba, cmd

I am creating a visual basic application where I have a Format drive button, which calls cmd to execute the format code as follows:

```
cmd_str = "cmd.exe /c format " + driveletter + " /q"
        Call Shell(cmd_str, vbNormalFocus)
```

where driveletter is the drive name. The problem is to execute the code, the user has to press **ENTER KEY** twice. I want the command so that the user don't have to press **ENTER** , so that I can further make the cmd process as hidden . Any suggetions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pipe the answers to the questions to it:

```
format c:
```

asks a question:

```
The type of the file system is xxx.

WARNING, ALL DATA ON NON-REMOVABLE DISK
DRIVE C: WILL BE LOST!
Proceed with Format (Y/N)?
```

if the answer is "y" you can do:

```
echo y | format c:
```

that will display the question and auto-enter the answer. If you want to suppress all output do you can do:

```
echo y | format c: > nul
```